# Text alignment line by line in android Text-view using Gravity

Tags: android, textview

Can we align our text line by line(I mean whatever the text we have selected that should be aligned instead of the whole text) in android text-view dynamically!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to draw text to your textview then. I have not seen a direct way to do it on a TextView

Comment: Can u please explain me with some sample. So We have to draw the text we have selected corresponding lines should be aligned to Right,Left and center with OnDrwaw()? For me if two lines of text I have typed in edittext/textview of android dynamically and if I have selected some text randomly which involves two lines then those two lines should be aligned..

Regards,

Vani